# Create Python Dictionary from feature classes, fields, and domains

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, dictionary

I want to create a Python dictionary with a Feature class as the key and the fields of the feature class and domains of the feature class as separate values. I'm starting off by simply attempting to add a Feature class (as a key) and its respective feature types(as values) but I'm not sure how to build that out. here's what I am trying to do by using list comprehension but my dictionary is empty:

```
    Dict = {fc.name: fc.featureType.values()for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(r"gdb")}

    print Dict
```

Any clues on how I can start this off?

Comment: As an alternative to list comprehension, and to try and learn more about using dictionaries with ArcPy I think you should start with an empty dictionary and then use Describe to determine and add the values as you iterate ListFeatureClasses.

Comment: Also, use the da cursors if you have ArcGIS 10.1 or higher, since they are at least 10 times faster than the 10.0 and prior cursors.

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/188566/64785

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to list comprehension, and to try and learn more about using dictionaries with ArcPy I think you should start with an empty dictionary and then use Describe to determine and add the values as you iterate ListFeatureClasses.

Answer (score 0):

The  *  argument passes all fields into arcpy.da.SearchCursor. The fields function returns a list of all the fields in your feature class.

```
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
features = {}
for fc in fcs:
    cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, '*')
    features[fc] = list(cursor.fields)
```